# Is declaring a variable as the interface type rather than its specific implementation a violation of KISS or YAGNI?

Tags: java

There is a HashMap instance. The only thing I will do with the instance is to call values() method described in the Map interface HashMap implements.

So I won't use any other possibilities interfaces provide.

Should I than declare the variable type of HashMap according to YAGNI and KISS or should I code to the interface and declare the type as Map?

Example of coding to the interface:

```
Map<Integer, String> langMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Example of class variable:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> langMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the link but it contains information about what is programming to an interface. While my question is about if in this example i should follow this rule or YAGNI and KISS since interfaces are not used here

Comment: The second answer in that link answers, IMHO, quite well *why* you should program to an interface.

Comment: I have red it and didn't find the answer. It proves programming to interface is good per se. And I agree with it. But it does not answer if I should program to interface when it is not (yet) needed.

Comment: I don't understand why that doesn't answer your question. The point is: you should program to an interface unless you have a good reason *not* to. I don't see any good reason not to, in your example.

Comment: Do you think YAGNI and KISS are not good reason to not use an interface in this example?

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski if you ain't gonna need methods specific to `HashMap`, use the interface. If you restrict yourself to methods on the `Map` interface, it's simpler.

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski the problem, I think, is that you think of it as something that is not the default way to code. But if you think of it as the default way to code, *not* programming this way would be a violation of KISS or YAGNI.

Comment: Ok. I understand now with the your comment and the  answer provided. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether to program against the interface or the concrete implementation should be determined by whether you need to access methods specific to `HashMap` that is not part of the interface. Using the `Map` interface is like saying *"I need functionality as specified by the `Map` interface, but does not really care how it is implemented."* Using the `HashMap` class directly is like saying *"I need the functionality in Map and it needs to be implemented as a `HashMap`"*.

Programming towards the interface is not violating neither KISS nor YAGNI, one could actually argue the other way around

- It is simpler (KISS) to program against a generic interface than a specific implementation.
- If a specific implementation is not needed, you should use the generic interface (YAGNI)